# How to parse HTTP Response data in Chrome with custom JS/Extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

There is this site, which shows some statistical user data, and it creates a HTML5 graph, based on a JSON response that it receives from the server.

I have manually examined the JSON response from the server, and it looks like the following:

```
{  
  "points":[  
  {  
     "date":"2019-07-29",
     "num":"4443"
  },
  {  
     "date":"2019-07-28",
     "num":"4596"
  },
  {  
     "date":"2019-07-27",
     "num":"5125"
  }
  ]
}
```

I would like to "download" this JSON response, and format it in a special way, but I can't make external requests to the endpoint (from an external application)

I would like to do it all, while being on the site.

Would it be possible to "inject" a javascript that would do this, or build a Chrome Extension that is able to read this response, and format it in the way that it's required?

Additionally, is there a way to "extend" the Developer Tools, with a little snippet, that would just format this data in a different way?

(If possible, I would like to do as few clicks as possible, to achieve this)

Comment: chrome web extension would be the way to go in your case

Comment: Your extension should have a content script that inserts a `<script>` with code ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)) that intercepts/hooks window.XMLHttpRequest and/or window.fetch (examples are easy to google up and there are libraries like xhook.js) to modify the response before it's returned to the site. Alternatively you can have a snippet in devtools which you'll run manually every time you visit the site, with the code that does the interception I mentioned.

Comment: @wOxxOm The last thing you mentioned sounds really good. So I just basically run a code in the DevTools console, that intercepts the response, and creates a file, or an alternative print? Or I can actually have a tab in the DevTools which is a little bit more elegant?

Comment: 1) To have a tab in devtools you need an extension. 2) The snippets thingy is [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets).